# PouchDB from Nodejs generate auth credentials

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I've been able to create databases from Nodejs using the Pouchdb module (after opening CORS).  Since I'm creating a db per user, I also need to create db specific credentials.  If talking directly to CouchDB, I'd use their APIS for: set_permissions or generate_api_key, however as I'm leveraging Pouchdb for all my Couchdb interactions, I'm hoping that there is a way to do it from pouch.

I've read through all the Pouch docs and poked around the code, but to no avail, so i'm turning to StackO with the hopes that someone else might have more insight on this question :)

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control CouchDB permissions from PouchDB, unless you write your own plugin in PouchDB for this. How to do that here - http://pouchdb.com/api.html#plugins

Apart from that, the closest thing on operating user login and credentials in CouchDB from PouchDB is this plugin:
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`pouchdb-authentication` is designed for use in the browser, but you can use `nano` to interface with CouchDB from Node. They've even got a section describing how to do authentication: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#using-cookie-authentication

Comment: I figured that would be the first response, but yeah, i'm talking about on the Node.js side.  I was just hoping that since I could create other databases with Pouchdb, I could do the next step which was setting an API key for them as well.  I just didn't wanna include nano since I was already set on using pouch to interact with couch and just needed this only last little thing.  I'll probably do it with request rather then a full wrapper like Nano or Cradle.